# UNHEX XML data from MySQL in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have selected XML data (TEXT column type) from MySQL using:

```
SELECT HEX(CONVERT(column USING utf16le)) FROM table
```

How can I get data back to XML in SQL server (now stored in NVARCHAR field)?

Comment: When downvoting, explain your reason. This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082433/exporting-table-with-blob-and-utf8-string-fields-from-mysql-to-ms-sql-server-201

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is to use this in SQL server:

```
CAST(
CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), column, 2) 
as nvarchar(max))
```